# Bootstrap - css - center options of dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I made a web page with different elements. One of these is a dropdown menu. I center an element in the middle of the web page:

[image]

but when I click the button of the dropdown menu and show the options, these do not center.

[image]

My HTML code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">   <!-- Solo indicamos container-fluid ya que si añadimos container éste ocupa el 60% del a página -->

    <div class="row text-center">
        <h1>MIQUEL ALIMENTACIÓ</h1>
        <h4 id='titEdicion'></h4><h4 id='titEstado'></h4>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div id="toolbar">

        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-addcom dropdown-toggle btn-size-edicion" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">SELECCIONAR EDICIÓ
                    <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu text-center" id="drEdicion">
                    <li"><a href=#>TOT</a></li>
                    <?php 
                    $result = dbQuery($conn, "SELECT * FROM produccion.ma_edicion");
                    while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){ ?>
                    <li><a href=#><?php echo $row[2]; ?></a></li>
                    <?php 
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
            <div class="row text-center">               
                <div>
                    <button id="newedition" type="submit" class="btn btn-group btn-size-edicion" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edicion'>NOVA EDICIÓ</button>

                </div>
            </div>         
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to add in the class='text-center', in the bootstrap this class to center the elements but in this case it doesn't work.

I put in jsfiddle an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/ruzD/DTcHh/26469/

With the last changes:

[image]

Comment: Can you add relevant CSS code for us?

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
<button class="btn btn-addcom dropdown-toggle btn-size-edicion" id="menu_list" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">SELECCIONAR EDICIÓ
              <span class="caret"></span></button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu text-center" id="drEdicion" aria-labelledby="menu_list">
                    <li"><a href=#>TOT</a></li>
              <?php 
                $result = dbQuery($conn, "SELECT * FROM produccion.ma_edicion");
                while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){ ?>
                    <li><a href=#><?php echo $row[2]; ?></a></li>
                <?php 
                }
                ?>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as actual dropdown list is absolutely positioned you can't center this list independently. Actually this is why it doesn't centers :) One of the solutions for you is to wrap your dropdown with `<div class="dropdown-wrapper">` and give it a style:

```
.dropdown-wrapper {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Width may be anything you want it to.

---

```css
.dropdown-wrapper {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown-wrapper">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-addcom dropdown-toggle btn-size-edicion" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">SELECCIONAR EDICIÓ
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu text-center" id="drEdicion">
      <li><a href=#>TOT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Anton Koning it's works! I have updated the question with a screenshot with the result. The options elements are not in center dropdown :(

Comment: @ruzD So is it working? When I open your fiddle and make adjustments from my answer it works pretty great. Please update your fiddle so I can see what else need adjustments

Comment: are right! In the Fiddle is works fine but in my code doesn't work. I will try it...